# PhoneGap Google Cloud Messaging Android problems

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, threadpoolexecutor

```
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-2
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue.addPluginResult(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:233)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.sendPluginResult(CordovaWebView.java:548)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin.sendPluginResult(Plugin.java:110)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin$1.run(Plugin.java:82)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-01 14:16:32.054: E/AndroidRuntime(17134):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I keep getting that error.  This happens after the application opens for the first time and registers the device with Google Cloud Messaging.  Everything appears to be going ok but then I pause the application and then once it resumes it calls the unregister function for some reason and then immediately crashes but then continues to register the device back again with Google Cloud Messaging so as soon as I reenter the application it is in the exact state it should be if it didn't force close.  And then if I pause and resume the application after that it doesn't force close anymore.

Has anybody else had any experience with this or any ideas to what is causing this?

I implemented the GCM PhoneGap plugin with  https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your code calls the unregister when your app resumes.

But I can fix the NullPointerException when this happens:

I debugged the GCM plugin code and discovered that the GCMPlugin.java file was at fault at line 75.

The if/else statement for unregistering did not provide a PluginResult!  So I added the following extra line and the NullPointerException went away:

```
else if (UNREGISTER.equals(action)) {
  GCMRegistrar.unregister(this.ctx.getContext());
  Log.v(ME + ":" + UNREGISTER, "GCMRegistrar.unregister called ");

  result = new PluginResult(Status.OK); //added line

}
```